# Using where clause with FeatureClassToFeatureClass?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, where-clause, error-000258

I want to split the shapefile with a field called FULLNAME and save those records with same FULLNAME to a new shapefile, which is the split by attribute. The following code has an error for the last line.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1693, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000258: Output C:\Users\TL\Desktop\831test\Splitbyattribute\Abilene Ln.shp already exists
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
```

Any suggestions?

```
import arcpy

def unique_values(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

inFC = r'C:\Users\TL\Desktop\831test\SpatialJoinName_proj.shp'
StreetNames = unique_values(inFC, 'FULLNAME')

#split the shapefile by different names
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(r"C:\Users\TL\Desktop\831test", "Splitbyattribute")
outputfolder = r"C:\Users\TL\Desktop\831test\Splitbyattribute"
for name in StreetNames:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFC, outputfolder, name, "FULLNAME = {0}".format(name))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1693, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

Comment: "FULLNAME = '{0}' ".format(name)

Comment: sometimes it is easier to define the where QRY outside loop in a variable

Comment: After I revised the code based on ziggy's help, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you there is already a shape file with that name in the folder. Check that no other outputs are in the folder or create a unique folder for each test run of the script.

Secondly your output filename has a space in it (Abeline Ln.shp) make sure you strip spaces out before you use it in your filename.

Comment: For your second recommendation he should use arcpy.ValidateTableName(name, outputfolder) to make sure he is creating a compliant shapefile name.  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/working-with-geodatabases.htm

Comment: The ValidateTableName helps a lot. REALLY good tool.